# crossed water pipes?

Tags: plumbing

I live in Portugal I have an electric   water heater for supplying hot water to the whole house.. A while back i decided to get a builder to install  a power jet shower,and this was mounted to the wall,and connectedto the hot and cold water outlets. Before the shower cabin there is a cold water safety tap.if this tap is open so as to have cold water in the bathroom as well as hot, i can use the bathroom normaly BUT have no hot water in the rest of the house. If i close this cold water safety tap completley,I can not use this bathroom as the water is scalding including the flush, but i have normal hot water everywhere else in the house . Have the pipes been bridged behind the shower  do you think? any suggestions?

Comment: Can you trace the pipe for this valve on both sides to the next thing (or things) they connect to? Also, is the valve in this shower a single handle valve? Lastly, are there any cold pipes feeding the electric water heater supply side that are turned off or possibly plugged.

Comment: Your local plumbers or plumbing inspectors will know about normal Portuguese plumbing design that we in the US won't. What is the normal function of this "cold water safety tap"? Is this something which is used only to cut-off cold water to the bathroom for repairs or is it used in the normal use of the bathroom.